# How to identify which UITextField is being modified inside a UICollectionView Cell?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, uicollectionviewcell

I have a some UITextFields inside a UICollectionViewCell and I want to know which of them is being modified. Every element has been made programmatically. The UICollectionViewCell has a swift class. The cell is repeated inside the UICollectionView about 5 times so I need to also in which cell the UITextField is.

Any suggestion about it?

Comment: Please [edit] your question with your actual code in the form of a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, in `cellForItemAt`, you need to assign a tag to the `textView` that will be displayed in that cell. It's easiest to identify it with the row number of the cell. For example:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    cell.textView.tag = indexPath.row
}
```

Next, inside `textViewDidChange` you put in a switch statement corresponding with the tag of the textView being modified. Inside each case you can perform whatever code you need knowing which textView you are modifying. For example:

```
func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
    switch textView.tag {
    case 0:
        // Code for first text view
        break
    case 1:
        // Code for second text view
        break
    case 2:
        // Code for third text view
        break
    case 3:
        // Code for fourth text view
        break
    default:
        // Code for fifth text view
        break
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I was looking for something more dynamic but at the end I opted for this solution